# Make li tag all shuffle up

Tags: html, html-lists, css

Is it possible to make all li items in a ul tag align up under each other rather than them all aligning to the longest. I know that doesnt make much sense so I did an example!! LOL

http://jsfiddle.net/S4GhV/1/

What I mean is, I want the boxes on the 2nd line to be under the boxes on the first row, for example, the 2nd box on the 2nd row to be tight under the 2nd box on the first row instead of having to align to the first box on the 2nd row horizontally. Same with box 3.

Hope that makes sense!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result you want by emulating columns, but it involves extra divs : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4GhV/26/)

Also, `li {vertical-align: bottom;}` would get everything tightly spaced, but it would only work for two rows and is probably not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question on SA and the answer is pretty much always to use this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

There is no pure CSS solution I'm afraid.